# Getting data from ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

im trying to send data with ajax:

```
var id_cookie = read_cookie('replay_id');
id_cookie = JSON.stringify(id_cookie);
$.ajax({
        url: remote_ip+':8124/show_replay',
        data: {cookie: id_cookie},
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "start_replay",
        cache: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Received data: "+data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }
});
```

and when I receive it I want to access the data

```
else if (req.method === "GET") {
```

// do something with the sent data here. req.data is undefined. How can I reach it?

Comment: Could you please clarify where do you expect to run the code "else if (req.method === 'GET') {"? You mean server-side or client-side? What is "req.data" you'd refer? Why it should be defined?

Comment: Using ports may cause to problem with ajax. Did you tried by removing comments.

Comment: it is on the server side. I want req.data to be the cookie: id_cookie

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, to get the value of "cookie" as a GET parameter, you can use:

```
$_GET["cookie"]
```

If you're not sure if it will be GET or POST, you can use:

```
$_REQUEST["cookie"]
```

I'd probably change the name of the data you're sending from "cookie" to something less ambiguous, to avoid confusion with actual cookies.